# how to decode the byte array(.h264 format) in to video in javascript?

Tags: javascript, node.js, h.264

I have a raw data bytes encoded with h264/avc.I need to read this Byte array and render it to video in JavaScript and display in html page.Can any body help ?

Comment: where is your byte stream. and is the byte stream in server side ? can you post your code here

Comment: I just have a file contain the byte array  file.avc

Comment: the source is the file.avc

Comment: aah ok then your bite stream is in server side . and you need to get that stream to client side right ?

Comment: yes ,the client in java script

Comment: here you can find the answer I think https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40387566/nodejs-how-to-send-a-readable-stream-to-the-browser

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two libraries that might help. Both of them are new to the field of WebM and .h264 decoders using javascript.

1)Broadway.js (https://github.com/mbebenita/Broadway)
2)Route9.js

I prefer Broadway.

Comment: thank you ,but can you help me I have no experiance in java script

Comment: Then you should first learn a bit of JS before trying this. Otherwise everything I explain will be "Greek".

Comment: @AreejHassoun try and learn a bit from w3schools and geeks4geeks. You would probably get the Broadway lib after getting a good idea of JS. Otherwise we're always here to help

Comment: Accept this answer if it helped :)